# i am using pemkey scp not wok in crontab. but run mannualy it work

Tags: linux, bash, server, ubuntu-18.04, scp

On a ubuntu setup I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
scp -i my.pem /home/fileupload/*txt username@ipserver:/home/loc
exit
```

i run mannualy it work without cron

thank you

Comment: Try to use an absolut path to the pem file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest to use absolute path to everything in your script.

```
#!/bin/bash 
/usr/bin/scp -i /home/<USER_NAME>/my.pem /home/fileupload/*txt username@ipserver:/home/loc
exit
```

Make sure the crontab is assigned to user `<USER_NAME>`

In crontab line use absolute path as well.